Same file ref unsupported? Workaround?
Trying the openapi-generator (from OpenApiTools) for the first time.
The openapi.yaml validates successfully.
It contains a lot of references like these:
    schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'

which lead to thousands of lines of error messages starting like
Error resolving schema #/components/schemas/ErrorMessage
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\dev\bitbucket\acme\openapi.yaml

When I search in GitHub issues I find dozens of issues with ref's (but no exact match), most of which are very old and unresolved.
Is there any workaround?
(And more generally: Is the project even still actively working on resolving bugs?)

Can you also post the ErrorMessage schema?
